# Arduino clock speed prescalers at start without fuses

Tags: arduino, atmega, clock-speed

I know it's possible to change the clock prescaler at runtime. But is there a way to set the prescaler that is used at boot on an ATMega328? I'm aware of the fuses, but those are pretty permanent. I want it to start up at 8MHz and see if it's running on a lower voltage backup battery first. And if not, then switch to 16MHz. I've tried doing it as the first thing in setup() but it doesn't seem fast enough.

Comment: but, if you select a clock divide by 8, shouldn't F_CPU now be 2MHZ instead of 16MHZ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm aware of the fuses, but those are pretty permanent

You can use the CLKDIV8 fuse, it only controls the preloaded cpu divider value so I don't consider it a permanent change.
The fuse sets the default loaded value to CLKPR (Clock prescale register) to either

- clk/1
- clk/8

Then in your code you can just set the divider to clk/1 to restore the cpu speed to 16MHz

---

I'm not sure but unless the bootloader is adaptive this change may affect the UART speed and create problems with the Arduino bootloader, this needs to be tested.

---

I did a test with my Arduino pro mini (m328p). After enabling the CLKDIV8 fuse using an external programmer, the Arduino bootloader becomes unresponsive and I don't see any way to override the UART speed that Arduiono IDE tries to use.

---

### Updated Solution

I found another solution that doesn't need to change the bootloader, you just create a new profile for the board that has the CLDIV8 fuse enabled.

You need to modify the file **boards.txt** (e.g. arduino-1.5.5\hardware\arduino\avr\boards.txt), the baud rate for each board is stored there.

Locate the section that refers to your board, for example in my case

```
## Arduino Pro or Pro Mini (5V, 16 MHz) w/ ATmega328
## -------------------------------------------------
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328=ATmega328 (5V, 16 MHz)

pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.upload.maximum_size=30720
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.upload.maximum_data_size=2048
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.upload.speed=57600

pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDA
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.bootloader.file=atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328.hex

pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.build.mcu=atmega328p
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.build.f_cpu=16000000L
```

Now copy and paste that section to create a duplicate entry that we are going to modify. In that entry you'll have to change the name so that it doesn't conflict with the existing one (any new name will do), and set the baud rate to 1/8 of the one that was originally used.
I'm showing the changes in bold

[image]

The old entry with the new one following it look like this in my case:

```
## Arduino Pro or Pro Mini (5V, 16 MHz) w/ ATmega328
## -------------------------------------------------
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328=ATmega328 (5V, 16 MHz)

pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.upload.maximum_size=30720
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.upload.maximum_data_size=2048
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.upload.speed=57600

pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDA
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.bootloader.file=atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328.hex

pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.build.mcu=atmega328p
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.build.f_cpu=16000000L

## Arduino Pro or Pro Mini (5V, 16 MHz) w/ ATmega328 CLKDIV8
## -------------------------------------------------
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8=ATmega328 (5V, 16 MHz) CLKDIV8

pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8.upload.maximum_size=30720
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8.upload.maximum_data_size=2048
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8.upload.speed=7200

pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDA
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8.bootloader.file=atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328.hex

pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8.build.mcu=atmega328p
pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328CLKDIV8.build.f_cpu=16000000L
```

After saving the file you'll see a new entry in Arduino IDE, by using it you will be able to program the modified board.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @adamhaile unfortunately changing the fuse will make Arduino bootloader unresponsive, this can only be used with an external programmer.

Comment: hahaha... was just testing that myself. and yup... no go. darn :(

Comment: @AdamHaile I also tried with [xLoader](http://russemotto.com/xloader/) that has the option to set the UART speed. I used 7200 but it didn't work either (1/8 of 57600).

Comment: The trick is to use a modified boot loader that is configured to generate the expected baud rate from the initial fuses.

Comment: @AdamHaile I found a solution, read the updated answer

Comment: Interesting... though, the fuses are the same in both. Shouldn't the low fuses for the CLKDIV8 version be 0x7F so that CLKDIV8 is actually set?

Comment: Why do you change `pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.upload.speed` (baudrate) rather than `pro.menu.cpu.16MHzatmega328.build.f_cpu` (system clock rate)?

Comment: @jippie `f_cpu` will not have any effect on the used baud rate so the communication with the bootloader will not work. `f_cpu` is related to the calculation of delays or baudrate of the mcu etc, and although the calculated results will be wrong for 1/8 setting they will be correct when the full speed is restored. If someone intends to use the board permanently  with a specific divider then the f_cpu value can be modified.

Comment: @AdamHaile I changed the CLKDIV8 using AVRstudio and an external programmer (I just wrote the new fuse values leaving the bootloader intact), so I focused on the changes needed in order to fix the communication between the Arduino IDE and bootloader. If you intend to write a new bootloader and change the fuses from the Arduino IDE then I guess these need to be changed too although I didn't try it so I'm not sure of the result.

Comment: Ahh, I just always change the fuses in that file and then flash the bootloader from the Arduino IDE to change the fuses... because I'm lazy :P

Comment: @alexan_e of course, you are right. The bootloader isn't changed, only the compiled sketch. Probably the serial interface won't work as expected during low F_CPU.

Comment: @AdamHaile In that case you can also change the fuses in the new setting, it's up to you.

Comment: @jippie Yes, I expect the serial library to misbehave while the cpu core is operating in a frequency different than the one used in the F_CPU property. This will also be the case for a board using the default fuse values if a user decides to change the clock divider inside the executable code. Delays, timers, PWM, everything will be several times slower that intended originally.